# Amazon payment method checkout error

Tags: payment-methods, amazon

after adding button on cart page have the error if i click on checkout page

```
Invalid method Mage_Core_Block_Template::isPopup(Array (
)
)
with trace :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the block type in your layout definition. It looks like you are doing a `block type="core/template" ...` when really, the block type should the block class that contains this `isPopup` function.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply can you guide me littlebit more that layout defination of theme or amazonpayment or checkoutpage ?

Comment: Apparently, it's an issue that has been reported: https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-plugin/issues/274. Just open up the template file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/amazon_payments/button.phtml` and replace "<?php print $this->isPopup(); ?>" by "false"